# how to make a profile entry read only except for site managers

Tags: users, buddypress, profiles

I have set some extra profile fields set in buddypress (under users profile fields), and I want to make sure they are read only with the exception of site administrators.

How do I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide profile fields on the edit screen from everyone except site admins - therefore they can only be edited by site admins. They will still be visible on the public profile screen. You can get the field id by looking at the url in wp-admin when you edit that field, or just rolling over the edit button. Add this function to your child-theme functions.php or [bp-custom.php](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/bp-custom-php/)

```
function arcee_hide_profile_fields( $retval ) {

    if( is_super_admin () )
        return $retval;

    if(  bp_is_profile_edit()  )
        $retval['exclude_fields'] = '3,43,253'; //field ID's separated by comma

    return $retval;

}
add_filter( 'bp_after_has_profile_parse_args', 'arcee_hide_profile_fields' );
```

Comment: instead of hiding, how about locking?  e.g. read only?

Comment: Making a field viewable but read only on the edit screen will require creating a template overload of this file: bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\profile\edit.php and adjusting as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet to your child-theme functions.php or [bp-custom.php](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/bp-custom-php/)

```
function bpfr_hide_profile_edit( $retval ) {    
// remove field from edit tab
if(  bp_is_profile_edit() ) {       
    $retval['exclude_fields'] = '2'; // field ID's separated by comma
}   
// allow field on register page
if ( bp_is_register_page() ) {
    $retval['include_fields'] = '2'; // field ID's separated by comma
    }       

// hide the field on profile view tab
if ( $data = bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=2' ) ) : 
    $retval['exclude_fields'] = '2'; // field ID's separated by comma   
endif;  

return $retval; 
}
add_filter( 'bp_after_has_profile_parse_args', 'bpfr_hide_profile_edit' );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer - thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much jim,  however I don't see make it read-only.  it's ok that everyone sees it, I just want it locked except site admins.  THanks